# Consistent IP Addresses for Auto Scaling / Load Balanced Instances

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, containers, load-balancing, elastic-ip

**The Setup**

- ECS (Containerized) Application (Node.js, API Only)
- Auto Scaling Group for ECS Container Instances
- Load Balancer in front of auto scaling group
- VPC covering all instances and ELB
- Database hosted in another VPC, not managed explicitly ([MongoDB Atlas](http://www.mongodb.com/Atlas)), likely not the same region.

**The Problem**

I want my database to use good security policies, therefore I opt for whitelisting IPs as Atlas recommends - rather than opening up my database to the world with `0.0.0.0/0`.

Each server has its own IP address, and in an autoscaling event it would need to be added by automation to the Atlas security rules (which is possible, not ideal).

How can I (using NAT Gateways? Elastic IPs?) get one IP for all of my load balanced instances.

**Failed Solutions?**

I tried using a NAT Gateway, essentially [scenario 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html) where all my of instances were in a private subnet, the NAT was in a public subnet with internet access, and the instances went through it to get to the database. This worked! Elastic IP on the NAT and I was able to authorize it on Atlas **however** it had weird issues where the instance wouldn't respond for 65 - 75 seconds, intermittently when pinged. I suspect this is due to the fact that it's not technically available on the internet and there's some routing that I don't fully understand happening. Once you got a `200` though everything would work fine, for a bit, then another 70 second latency and back to good again...

Really appreciate the input, have been searching for a while with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a VPC peering connection?  As long as the VPC CIDR blocks do not overlap, this is a good option because you can use security groups and private IPs between the peered VPCs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html

Comment: Based on my understanding of peering connections it wouldn't work as I have no access to the Atlas VPC, and it's not in the same region.

Comment: You should update your question with that information, as it is very pertinent.

Comment: @joel.bowen did you find a solution ?